# Point of Intersection between two lines

Tags: vectors

Question: Find the point of intersection between two lines:

Line 1:
[image]
and Line 2: [image]

I tried doing this question by inputting the x,y,z values from line 2 into line 1 but I got stuck and I don't think I got the correct answer. Can anyone help me out? If so, I'd really appreciate it! Thanks.

This was my most recent attempt to do the question:

[image]

As you can see, the answer that I got for s, was 38/13. Which I know is not correct. The area where I highlighted in pink, I feel that's where I messed up but I am not sure. I apologize if the camera quality isn't good.

Comment: 1) Write line 1 in vector form.
2) See if there are numbers $t,s$ such that $L_1(t)=L_2(s)$ (try the first two components, then see if those numbers work for the third).
3) If so, knowing 'when' the lines meet, you can find out 'where' by evaluation.

Comment: Substituting gives $s=-8$ so $(7,7,-3)$ is the answer, one can verify it fits both lines. If the textbook gives another answer, maybe it's incorrect.

Comment: If you show us your calculations, Panda, we may be able to show you where you went wrong (if you did go wrong) and what you could do instead.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin, I'm 99% sure the answer that you gave is correct because the answer allows the equation line 1 to be correct. However, I am still stuck on how you got that answer. I am trying to fix my mistakes to get to the answer but I'm still getting other incorrect answers.  If it's possible, can you explain how you got the answers?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I just posted and edited my calculations.

Comment: When you get $\frac{-6-3s}{6}=\frac{-14-4s}{6}=\frac{-30-6s}{6}$ it's **two** equations like $(1)=(2)=(3)$ is $(1)=(2)$ and $(1)=(3)$, consider them seperately, $-6-3s=-14-4s$ leads to $14-6=-4s+3s$ so $s=-8$, and $-6-3s=-30-6s$ leads to $6s-3s=-30+6$ so $s=-8$ too. Then you can simply put $s=-8$ into the second line equation.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin. Okay, now I understand. I thought I had to multiply the denominator with the numerator to isolate the numerator. I didn't know that I could just ignore the denominator (if both denominators have the same value)  and focus on only the numerator. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You can't, but $\frac{A}{6}=\frac{B}{6}\Leftrightarrow A=B$

Comment: The mistake had nothing to do with numerators and denominators, the mistake was going from $a=b=c$ to $a-b-c=0$. You can't do that. $5=5=5$ but $5-5-5\ne0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Okay, I got it. Thank you for the explanation!